# Hyperlink Navigationuri with parameter wpf

Tags: wpf, query-string, hyperlink, parameter-passing

I want to set navigateURI to the dynamically created hyperlink. I am using the following code but it is not navigation to the page if i pass parameter. showing the following error.

Code:

```
   Hyperlink hlProduct = new Hyperlink(new InlineUIContainer(img));
   hlProduct.NavigateUri = new Uri("Player.xaml?id=109", UriKind.Relative);

public partial class Player : Page
{        
    public Player(string id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

Error:

Cannot create object of type 'ProductPlayer'. CreateInstance failed, which can be 
  caused by not having a public default constructor for 'ProductPlayer'.  Error in markup 
  file 'Player.xaml' Line 1 Position 7.

Geetha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the id parameter from Player class, should be as below:

public Player() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
     }

To extract the parameters use **NavigationService.CurrentSource**, which return uri object. Parse this object to get id value.